# How to call a one button by another button in a single activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

In my code I am trying to go on buttonOff button when I click on Buttonon
       and viceversa.but i am getting some problem in onclick method code.
      How can I get button on by clicking buttonoff on same activity.

```
  public class FAN extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button buttonFanOn;
       Button buttonFanOff;

          buttonFanOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonon);

          buttonFanOff = (Button) findViewById(buttonoff);

          buttonFanOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                   buttonFanOn.setId(R.id.buttonon);


              }
          });
       }
```

Comment: buttons can't be called. you can call the method it triggers. Just create a ClickListener seperate outside of the button

Comment: First clear the requirement.

Comment: @Ankita the requirement is clear, the solution is simple, it's just a little thinking exercise he should work on

Comment: *I am trying to go on buttonOff button* => this makes no sense, too bad the "question" starts with that. Voting to close.

Comment: why are you changing the view ID? what are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger `Button` click event programmatically by using `performClick()` function into another button click.

```
public class FAN extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button buttonFanOn;
       Button buttonFanOff;

          buttonFanOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonon);

          buttonFanOff = (Button) findViewById(buttonoff);

          buttonFanOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                   buttonFanOn.performClick();//here your click event occures for On button


              }
          });


          buttonFanOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                   buttonFanOff.performClick();//here your click event occures for Off button


              }
          });
       }
```